# Best way to implement dynamically scheduled API calls

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am currently trying to implement a service that allows the user to schedule an event. By doing this, I would need to have a queue or other persistent data storage mechanism that will hold these unsent API calls/data required to make these calls, and when the time arises have these API calls made. What would be the simplest way of doing this? Initially I was thinking of using airflow job or something similar, but there is the chance that there can be hundreds of events scheduled. Would something like SQS work? A couple important things to note is that the events can only be scheduled in one hour increments but there is no limit on the number of events that can be scheduled at that one hour time. Also, the endpoint for all the events is the same, with the only differing thing is an ID that is specified by the user when they initially schedule the event.

Comment: SQS doesn't sound like the right place to store the scheduled events because you can't retrieve only those messages that relate to a specific time. Perhaps store in DynamoDB with an indexed event time/schedule attribute and use EventBridge Scheduler to run a Lambda function or Step Functions workflow every hour, query the DynamoDB table for events scheduled at the current hour, and process accordingly.